# PHP/MYSQL using while loop to get current row then output data from column 1, then proceed to do the same for the following rows

Tags: php, mysql, image, dynamic, while-loop

Ok so i have a mysql database with a table called fotf_images, which as you can guess stores image information like location, name, etc..

Now what im doing is dynamically adding img tags for each row using the following code:

```
$count = 0;
                        $currentcount = $count; //gets row by count number

                        while($count < $numrows)
                        {
                            echo '<img src="" width="250" height="200" class="fotfimage" vspace="2">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';

                            $count++;
                            if($count == $numrows)
                            {
                                break;  
                            }

                        }
```

Now what i need to do is actually display the image based on the data in the currently selected rows column 1. So for example, if there is 3 rows, then my current code will add 3 img tags, i then need to add the src for each img tag based on the field value for each rows' column 1 which stores its location.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand you right:
The source of each picture is stored in the first column? If I got this right maybe following code will help you.

```
<?php


$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM fotf_images");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
     $columnId = 0;
     echo '<img src="'.$row[{$columnId}].'" width="250" height="200" class="fotfimage" vspace="2">';

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ?

```
$my_array = mysql_fetch_row ($result)
echo '<img src="'.$my_array[1].'" width="250" height="200" class="fotfimage" vspace="2">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
```

Comment: its kind of hard to explain. Basically everytime the loop loops over a row i need it to add 1 img tag and make the src of the img tag the first column of the row its currently on, then proceed to the next row and do the same.